# How to trigger shell/script after a snapshot is taken?

Tags: raspberry-pi, motion, motion-detection

Within the Motion (Motion-project) (https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion) configuration/process.

Is there a way to trigger a shell/script after a snapshot is taken?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your motion.conf :

`#Command to be executed when a picture (.ppm|.jpg) is saved (default: none)
 #To give the filename as an argument to a command append it with %f
; on_picture_save value`

Remove `;` before "on_picture_save" and edit your value with a shell command to execute your script.